# PHP Codeigniter Variable Scope Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't figure out why this code is outputting a Notice error

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {   

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() 
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['brand_title']   = 'Company Brand';

    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo $brand_title;
    }
}
```

I get a **Undefined variable: brand_title** error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
echo $this->data['brand_title'];
```

If you prefer your way, you could do it like this:

```
extract($this->data);
echo $brand_title;
```

But `extract()` is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this like that in the same controller
only in view of the same method you can use this

but if you want to use it like your post then it should be like that

```
echo $this->data['brand_title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$brand_title` variable doesn't exist. That's why it's generating the `Undefined variable` error. If you want to store it in a variable and use that, try this:

```
 public function index()
 {
     $brand_title = $this->data['brand_title'];
     echo $brand_title;
 }
```